# How to show alert when / if input value live change using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show alert if input value change. I am using jQuery, so here is a demo what i am trying to do but alert not showing / not working. Thanks

```js
$(".d1, .d2").click( function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
$(".input").attr('value', $this.text());
});

$(".input").change( function() {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

```css
.d1, .d2 {cursor:pointer;border:1px solid black;margin-top:10px;padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" value="" /><p/>
<a class="d1">Demo 1</a>
<a class="d2">Demo 2</a>
```

Comment: call change() event directly after setting value. like :: $(".input").attr('value', $this.text()).change();

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) method to set value of `input`element, Since you are using the `change` event in `input` on programatically changing the value it will not execute. You need to use [`.trigger(event)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```js
$(".d1, .d2").click( function (e) {
var $this = $(this);
$(".input").val($this.text()).trigger('change');
});

$(".input").change( function() {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

```css
.d1, .d2 {cursor:pointer;border:1px solid black;margin-top:10px;padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input" value="" /><p/>
<a class="d1">Demo 1</a>
<a class="d2">Demo 2</a>
```